# Console warning: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got a problem here, I don't know what is wrong in my code, but I got a warning in my console, how can I remove this warning?

> [Vue tip]: `<todo-item v-for="todoItem in todos">`: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key for more info.
> (found in `<Root>`)

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Vue Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png">
        <script src="scripts/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="app">
            <p>{{ msg }}</p>
            <p v-bind:title="message">
                Hover your mouse over me for a few seconds to see my dynamically bound title!
            </p>
            <div>
                <p v-if="seen">This text will show or hide if the button was clicked.</p>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="isSeen">{{ isSeenText }}</button>
            </div>
            <ol>
                <li v-for="todo in todos">
                    {{ todo.text }}
                </li>
            </ol>
            <p>Total count: {{ todos.length }}</p>
            <div v-bind:title="reverseMessageText">
                <p>{{ reverseMessageText }}</p>
                <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Data binding: <strong>{{ nameOfUser }}</strong></p>
                <input type="text" v-model="nameOfUser">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ol>
                    <todo-item v-for="todoItem in todos" v-bind:data="todoItem"></todo-item>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
var appComponent = Vue.component('todo-item', {
    template: '<li>id: {{ data.id }}<br>text: {{ data.text }}</li>',
    props: [
        'data'
    ]
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        msg: 'Hello World!',
        message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date(),
        seen: true,
        isSeenText: 'Now you don\'t',
        todos: [
            {
                text: 'Learn JavaScript'
            },
            {
                text: 'Learn Vue'
            },
            {
                text: 'Build something awesome'
            }
        ],
        reverseMessageText: 'Hello World from Vue.js!',
        nameOfUser: 'John Rey'
    },
    methods: {
        reverseMessage: function() {
            this.reverseMessageText = this.reverseMessageText.split('').reverse().join('');
        },
        isSeen: function() {
            this.seen = !this.seen;
            this.isSeenText = this.seen ? 'Now you don\'t' : 'Now you see me';
        }
    }
});


console.log
```

[image]

Here is the link that Vue suggested [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key). I think i don't have any error, I want to solve that warning but I cannot find where's the cause, btw I'm newbie here to Vue.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The answer is listed explicitly in the [documentation you linked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)...

```
<todo-item v-for="todoItem in todos"
           v-bind:data="todoItem"
           v-bind:key="todoItem.text"></todo-item>
```

---

To summarise some information from the comments below... you use `:key` to let the component know how to identify individual elements. This allows it to keep track of changes for Vue's *reactivity*.

It's best to try and bind the `:key` to some uniquely identifying property of each item. For example, an `id`.

Comment: In my case i want the entire todo object to be passed along to <todo-item>, I don't want to pass only the .text. Is this possible?

Comment: @kokodoko the entire item **is** passed via the `data` property. You use `key` to let the component know how to identify individual elements

Comment: ok, thanks, so key is just a way for vue to keep track of things, so you need to have some value to use as a key.

Comment: @Kokodoko yes, that's it exactly

Answer (score 15):

My solution to a similar problem looked like this:

```
- <el-radio v-for="option in field.options"> ...
+ <el-radio v-for="(option, index) in field.options" :key="index"> ...
```

Or using `v-bind` syntax for `index`:

```
+ <el-radio v-for="(option, index) in field.options" v-bind:key="index"> ...
```

Comment: This is a great solution. My elements arent really unique. So this solves it.

Comment: @khan unless your "option" list is static this is a really bad solution to the OP's question.  Since the items rendered will be identified by their position in the list, anything that reorders that list risks hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any field of your data as a key. In addition you can use the default id. Furthermore you can define a "key" in your data as in the code below:

```
Vue.component('task-list', {
template:  `
<div><slot>
    <task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.key">  {{task.description}}</task>
</slot></div>
`,
data () {
    return {
        tasks: [
                {description:"Go to market", completed:false, key:"asd"},
                {description:"Wake up ", completed:true, key:"rty"},
                {description:"Sleep", completed:false, key:"terw"},
                {description:"Have breakfast", completed:true, key:"jdr"},
        ]
    };
},
});
Vue.component('task', {
   template: `<li><slot></slot></li>`
});
```

In the place of the key in the task.key you can put one of the field names including the hidden id.