# Vuejs Get a button to only print once inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So basically what i am trying to do is to get a button to only show for the first item within the v-for. I want to be able to add a button and for it to be only printed once no matter how many times the v-for loops round.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/75549/) with the code and also code posted below

```
  <div v-for="item in userInformation">
  <p>{{item.username}}</p>
  <p>{{item.email}}</p>
  <p>{{item.age}}</p>
  <button> Only Show Once</button> //Only show this once
  </div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be between the first and the second item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`v-once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) directive to render a view only once in Vuejs, but your `v-for` needs to have a [:key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476942/console-warning-component-lists-rendered-with-v-for-should-have-explicit-keys) bind to the index of your loop but still didn't work for me:

Another quick way to do this is, use the key to get the last iteration:

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in userInformation" :key='index'>
```

and place this logic inside your button

```
 <button v-if='index === userInformation.length -1 '> Only Show Once</button>
```

This [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/50wL7mdz/75553/) will show the button only once and after the last iteration.

Comment: No joy with that. The button also needs to be on the first loop

Comment: Then change the `v-if` logic to `v-if='index === 0'` like this https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/50wL7mdz/75555/

Comment: If you want it to appear even before any text, then move the button upwards like https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/50wL7mdz/75556/

Comment: Yea I know i could have done that from the start but i'm looking it inside the first iteration

Comment: I don't understand. You said in your question you only wanted the button to appear once. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I thought i was specific enough. "get a button to only show for the first item within the v-for"  That's exactly what I want to do. The button will only show within the first iteration of the v-for and not any other iterations

Comment: have you even looked at this? https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/50wL7mdz/75555/ unless my english is failing me, that is exactly what you are asking for

Comment: Apologies i missed your previous comment with that! Thanks alot!!