# How do I tell vue that I intend to use the simple rendering in v-for?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a static array of 3 buttons that will never change while the component is active.
How do I tell Vue to use the simple rendering method without it complaining about:
component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys.

The Vue docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key says:

> It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible,
> unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally
> relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

My static array of static buttons should qualify for this "exception", how do I tell Vue this is the intention?

I don't want to have warnings in my code.

(SO question [Console warning: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476942/console-warning-component-lists-rendered-with-v-for-should-have-explicit-keys) is the oposite of what I'm asking about.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this:

```
<div v-for="(slide, index) in currentState.slides" :key="index">
   <!-- more code here -->
</div>
```

This piece got rid of the warning and things went well. What I am doing here is that I am passing the index along with the value in the array and use the index as key.